# CycloneDX v2.1.2 - How to Generate Dependency Graph For .NET Framework Projects using CycloneDX v2.1.2

Tags: maven-bom

I downloaded latest CycloneDX Tool for .NET with v2.1.2. In the latest release Dependency Graph feature is added. But, when I run the CycloneDX tool against .NET Framework solution e.g. MVC project solution, the resultant SBOM file does not contain proper dependency graph. CycloneDX looks for *project.assets.json* file for determining the transitive dependencies. But, MVC project(.NET Framework) does not have *project.assets.json* file. I tried to generate this file by running dotnet restore command but I get message "Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore". Package management format used is *packages.config*.

**How to generate dependency graph for .NET Framework projects using CycloneDX?**

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to generate an accurate dependency graph for packages.config files. All dependencies are listed in packages.config. So there's not really a good way to determine if a dependency is only required by other dependencies (transitive), or if it is also a direct dependency of the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late and the new version of CycloneDx has already fix it. But if some search a tool to create a dependency graph for .net (nuget) you can look at
[component-detection](https://github.com/microsoft/component-detection).